# mongodb cursor map in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here I have created a collection with a single document

```
db.getCollection('example').insert({"example":1});
```

[MongoDB - Cursor - Map](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map)

On the mongo shell command, I am able to get the output using the mongo cursor map command.
However, I am struggling to find the equivalent PHP driver implementation.[PHP Mongo Cursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php). Any alternatives?

```
db.getCollection('example').find({"example":1},{"_id":1}).map(function(doc) { 
    return {'id': doc._id.str }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find Doctrine implementation of ArrayCollection or similar of that to be useful with their own iterators map methods doctrine/common lib or doctrine/collection as well. 
In your particular case i'd recommend to implement simple generator with callable argument (if you need to left functionality of Cursor loading) or just use basic array_map function around result of iterator_to_array with Cursor argument. 
Cheers.

UPD: 
Here simple generator example:

`php
    function map_traversable(callable $mapper, \Traversable $iterator) {
        foreach($iterator as $val) {
            yield $mapper($val);
        }
    }`

In that case you will walk throught the data once.

Comment: As you can see this question is clearly a duplicate to OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307610/mongodb-get-id-as-string-in-find-query) and like as said [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26469064#26469064) `array_map` or `foreach` loop is the way to go.