# Get Mongo _id as string and not ObjectId in find query without aggregation

Tags: mongodb

This has basically been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307610/mongodb-get-id-as-string-in-find-query) but there wasn't a clear answer to a very specific part of the question.

I have a simple query:

```
db.getCollection('contact').find({"xx" : "yy" }, {"_id" : 1})
```

Which returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("562a6300bbc948a4315f3abc") }
```

I would like to return just the id string value, i.e.

```
{ "_id" : "562a6300bbc948a4315f3abc" }
```

I'm not worried about what the field name would be, just the string value.

The answers in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307610/mongodb-get-id-as-string-in-find-query) suggest using aggregation or mapping functions (which as suggested in the related [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93200/discussion-between-faiz-and-user3100115) can't be as fast or simple as the simple find query), but my question is **can this be done using just a simple `find` query**, getting Mongo to do all the work.

I know this is wrong but to illustrate my line of thinking:

```
db.getCollection('contact').find({"xx" : "yy" }, {"_id.str" : 1})
db.getCollection('contact').find({"xx" : "yy" }, {"_id.value" : 1})
```

I understand the answer may well be as simple as, you can't.

Comment: If there are existing answers then those "are" the answers. If there is a different way then a new answer will be added there.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, I appreciate that, my concern is that the way the other question was asked the specific question I have isnt clear so I dont think it would be answered there without someone reading the entire chat.stackoverflow.com too. If someone answers there Im happy to delete this question.

Comment: Maybe you should go and have another look at the answers and you might just see something "new". There's no point asking the same thing as what has already been asked because that's called a "duplicate". New answers can be added to old questions.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, I see your new answer on the other question, unfortunately, that doesn't answer the specific part of my question, which is can this be done using just a simple find query (i.e. not with aggregation)

Comment: You cannot "alter documents" using find. That's also a straight up duplicate so don't bother asking. The aggregation framework and mapReduce are the only things that alter documents.

Comment: So the answer is, it can't be done. Thanks for your time.